# How do I group Dictionary Data with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, dictionary

I have my dictionary data in this format.

```
var data: [[String:AnyObject]] =

[
  [
    "id": "1",
    "title": "A Title",
    "Detail": "This is a String"
  ],      
  [
    "id": "2",
    "title": "A Title Again",
    "Detail": "This is a String"
  ],
  [
    "id": "3",
    "title": "B Title",
    "Detail": "This is a String"
  ],
  [
    "id": "4",
    "title": "B Title Again",
    "Detail": "This is a String"
  ]
]
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can group my tableView from [A-Z] like the prototype image below with Swift.

[image: Prototype]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a two step problem (that we'll solve in pure Swift). First, we need to determine what sections we have (in this case, just `A` and `B`. This is fairly simple:

```
var letters = Set<String>()

for element in data {
    var title = element["title"] as? String
    let letter = title?.substringToIndex(advance(title!.startIndex, 1))

    letters.insert(letter!)
}
```

We first create a set of `String` objects, so that each letter is represented just once. To get the first character (in pure Swift), we must use `substringToIndex` and pass in a `String.Index` value using `advance`. As a side note, if you'd like to normalize the letters, append `.uppercaseString` before inserting the letter into `letters`.

`print(letters)` will then output `[A, B]`.

––

Secondly, we need to sort `data` by the `title` key. Swift makes sorting quite easy:

```
data.sort { element1, element2 in
    let title1 = element1["title"] as? String
    let title2 = element2["title"] as? String

    return title1 < title2
}
```

You can then arrange the data however you like, now knowing how to both sort by key, and detect which letters to show. Hope this helps!

Comment: Many Thanks mate! This worked for me.  I have a little problem now. How do I add the letters to (sectionIndexTitlesForTableView) so it displays at the right. When I  `return letters` I get error  `'Set<String>' is not convertible to '[String]'`

Comment: You're welcome! You can use `let lettersArray: [String] = Array(letters)`, and that should fix that error. Please consider accepting the answer if it was useful :)

Comment: Thanks. I still have an issue :( Could you please guide me on how to return `numberOfSectionsInTableView`  and `numberOfRowsInSection` because for some weird reasons, my table repeated my dictionary data two times probably an error from `numberOfSectionsInTableView`

Comment: Could you update for swift 3 as `advance` is no longer in Swift 3?

Answer (score 1):

You want the [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/) API.

The table that your image shows is a plain table view with titles and sections.

Some of the methods you want to implement are `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `titleForHeaderInSection`. For the scrollable index alongside the table, you want `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView`. All of these methods are described in the link above.

You may consider sorting your array and breaking it up by letter of the alphabet, but doing so can be expensive, so don't do it while your user is scrolling.

Comment: Thanks @Moshe, could you guide me how I would sort my array and break it up by letter of the alphabet. I'm quite new to swift. Please forgive my 'basic' question.

Comment: There are some methods on NSArray that should help you. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what the "swift like" way to do this is, but look at the NSArray and NSPredicate classes, and see if those can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Environment: Xcode 12.5

Step 1: Grouping

```
struct Product {
    var id: String
    var title: String
    var detail: String
}

    //MARK: Grouping
    let data =  Dictionary.init(grouping: [Product(id: "1", title: "A Title", detail: "This is a String"),
                                           Product(id: "2", title: "A Title Again", detail: "This is a String"),
                                           Product(id: "3", title: "B Title", detail: "This is a String"),
                                           Product(id: "4", title: "B Title Again", detail: "This is a String")], by: {
        String($0.title.prefix(1))
    })
    
    lazy var dataSource: [(key: String, values: [Product])] = data.compactMap({(key: $0, values: $1)})
```

Step 2: Configure Tableview

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return self.dataSource[section].key
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.dataSource.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.dataSource[section].values.count
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.dataSource[indexPath.section].values[indexPath.row].title
        return cell
    }
}
```

End Result:
[image]